# Too many decimal places error

Tags: solidity, javascript, mocha

So I am putting together a test for my contract and this is the `it()` statement:

```
it('allows one account to enter', async () => {
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'wei')
    });
```

I am unclear as to why I am getting this error:

> Error: [ethjs-unit] while converting number 0.02 to wei, too many
>   decimal places

Does `web3.utils` no longer take care of the conversion or did I calculate the decimal places wrong?

Here is the snippet of the actual contract that assigns the amount of money:

```
function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wei` is the smallest unit of Ether and cannot be subdivided. This line:

```
web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'wei')
```

says to convert `.02 wei` to `wei`, which obviously cannot be done because `.02 wei` cannot exist to begin with, and it doesn't make sense to convert to and from the same units...

You probably meant to put:

```
web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether')
```

Which converts `.02 ether` to `wei` which is: `20000000000000000 wei` or `20 * 10^15 wei`

Comment: thanks Shawn, I guess I need to take a break from testing, totally missed that. That's why peer review is so important.